# Why do iterator's find and position have different function signatures?

Tags: rust, iterator

I am new to rust and I am using iterator and I have a problem.

When doing a find operation on iterator, there are two optional functions.

```rust
fn find<P>(&mut self, predicate: P) -> Option<Self::Item>
where
    P: FnMut(&Self::Item) -> bool,
```

and

```rust
fn position<P>(&mut self, predicate: P) -> Option<usize>
where
    P: FnMut(Self::Item) -> bool,
```

I can certainly understand the difference in their return values, but why do their `predicate`s have different types? One takes `Self::Item` as an argument, and one takes `&Self::Item`.

Answer (score 1):

`find()` need to not consume the `Item` because it's give it to you at the end, without a reference `find()` would give you the ownership of `Item` and so it would need to clone it.

`position()` doesn't give you `Item` at the end but a `usize` so there is no requirement, it can just give you ownership of `Item` without the need to clone it.

All of this is arbitrary choice since there is a lot of way to code similar functionality. For example, `iter.filter_map(predicate_a).next()` is mostly a `iter.find(predicate_b)` but give the ownership of `Item` to the predicate function.

Comment: Thank you very much. Suppose here there is a set `set = vec![1,2,3,4]` and the argument passed to `predicate` in `position()` is `&i32` and in `find()` is `&i32`. When will `&&i32` and `&i32` be distinguished? A concrete example would be great.

Comment: @progquester that not useful to know that, just smash `&` or `*` until compiler is happy, compiler will optimize all you code anyway. If you follow a simple "no double ref" in your function definition there is little chance you will doing bad code. To answer directly your question is impossible, find predicate would receive `&&i32` not `&i32`. If you want concrete example, provide concrete exemple in your question not in a comment on an answer that neither practical and clear.

Comment: That's exactly my problem ah, I didn't see the difference between providing `&i32` or `&&i32`, so I asked the question. In my mind, it's more consistent to unify the parameters of both functions.

Comment: `filter_map()` is not the same as `find()`, it uses the returned element instead of the passed one. Generally, iterator methods move to the predicate if they can, and borrow if they must.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman read twice, I never say the contrary, I used the word "mostly" and make a point to name it `predicate_a` to differentiate with `predicate_b` without give specific implementation and explain in the sentence after.